# Learning Rails -> Setup a Cookbook App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm new to Rails and trying to setup a cookbook app for practice. Here is what I have so far:

**DB Setup** - 3 tables (simplified for readability)

```
recipes (id, name, description)

recipe_ingredients (id, recipe_id, ingredient_id, qty, unit)

ingredients(id, name)
```

**Models**

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
end

class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredients
end
```

Here is my problem. I want to retrieve a list of ingredients for a recipe including qty and the unit used so I can iterate through it in my view.

Here is what I tried (local variables shown, I know I have to use instance variable to use in view) :

```
recipe = Recipe.first
```

`recipe.ingredients` -> gives me all ingredients for that recipe from the ingredients table, but it does not include the qty & unit from recipe_ingredients table.

`recipe.recipe_ingredients` -> gives me all related records in the recipe_ingredients table but I only get ingredient_id and not the actual ingredient name.

How can I retrieve the recipe and all its ingredients including quantity and unit using the least amount of queries? I think it would be 2 in this case.

Thank you,

Leo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `includes` method. You need something like this :

```
recipe = Recipe.includes(:ingredients, :recipeingredients).first
```

this will return the first recipe with all it's associated ingredients and recipe ingredients.

Comment: Yep, way better than my suggestion. Wish I knew about it before!

Comment: @RailsOuter Need some more clarification. I do not see a way to access qty, unit and ingredient name from the formed recipe object. Lets say I want to access the info about the first ingredient:

recipe.recipe_ingredients[0].qty -> would give me the qty
recipe.recipe_ingredients[0].unit -> would give me the unit

but how would I get the ingredient name? Sure I could do: recipe.ingredients.find(recipe.recipe_ingredients[0].ingredient_id).name
but that's an extra DB trip and creates the N + 1 problem

Comment: @LeoNet, I don't see an N + 1 problem here, all the information is loaded in the first call to recipe, where is the extra DB trip?

Comment: @RailsOuter when I need to retrieve the name of the ingredient. I do not see a way to access it from the created object at the same time I'm getting the qty and unit from the join table.

Comment: @RailsOuter OK I see it now. All I had to do is: recipe.recipe_ingredients.ingredients.name and it all works. Thank you.

Comment: And just to make it easier to use I defined a method called `name` in `RecipeIngredient` model with this: `self.ingredient.name`. This way I do not have odd looking code like ingredient.ingredient.name in my view just ingredient.name.

Comment: @LeoNet, nice, also take a look at the Law of Demeter.

Answer (score -1):

You can add [delegation](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) to increase the functionality of your `RecipeIngredient` instances.

I would especially check out the `prefix` section, otherwise you would only be able to delegate `name` to one class.